# Check whether a tree is a binary tree using Prolog

Tags: prolog

Binary tree is defined as Tree(Node, Left, Right) in my implementation.

I'm writing a isBinaryTree(*Term*) function to check whether *Term* is a binary tree, given that Term can be any Prolog term.

Here is my implementation:

```
isBinaryTree(nil).
isBinaryTree(Tree(_,left,right)) :- isBinaryTree(left), isBinaryTree(right).
```

But it return "no" on the following input.

```
isBinaryTree(Tree(a, nil, nil)).
```

While it return "yes" on

```
isBinaryTree(nil)
```

Why isBinaryTree(Tree(a, nil, nil)) won't return me a "yes" on prolog?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Upper-case letter to represent variable in Prolog.